# Celery Flower for several project

Tags: python, celery, flower

I've several project's on one server, which use celery package with different BROKER_URL.
Flower allows one BORKER_URL as command option:

```
celery flower --broker=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//
```

How can i run one flower process for all brokers?

Comment: Can't find a way to run one flower for two brokers. If i give two `broker` arguments, it throws error. If i try to instantiate separately, it gives socket error as previous process is running on same port. Why do you want to run one flower for all brokers?

Comment: Because it is easier to monitor projects from one address.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.
I run multiple instance, one per broker.